# Why overloading does not occur?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

I have the following class:

```
class CrmToRealTypeConverter : IConverter
{
    #region IConverter Members

    public object Convert<T>(T obj)
    {
        return Convert(obj);
    }

    #endregion

    private DateTime? Convert(CrmDateTime obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (DateTime?)obj.UserTime : null;
    }

    private int? Convert(CrmNumber obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (int?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    private decimal? Convert(CrmDecimal obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (decimal?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    private double? Convert(CrmDouble obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (double?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    private float? Convert(CrmFloat obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (float?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    private decimal? Convert(CrmMoney obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (decimal?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    private bool? Convert(CrmBoolean obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (bool?)obj.Value : null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to specialize the Convert method with concreate types.
Currently it just loops recursively in `Convert<T>()` until a stack overflow occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late-binding doesn't happen the way you think it does; the compiler binds the call to `Convert(obj)` in the`public object Convert<T>(T obj)` method to the *same* method (recursive call). The behaviour you appear to be expecting is that the CLR will dynamically choose the most appropriate overload to execute at run-time, but it doesn't work that way. Try something like this instead:

```
public object Convert<T>(T obj)
{
   if (obj == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    var cdt = obj as CrmDateTime;   
    if (cdt != null)
        return Convert(cdt); // bound at compile-time to DateTime? Convert(CrmDateTime)

    var cn = obj as CrmNumber;    
    if (cn != null)
        return Convert(cn); // bound at compile-time to int? Convert(CrmNumber)

    // ...    

    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert " + obj.GetType());
}
```

If you prefer, you can use reflection here. Such a solution would look something like:

```
// Making the method generic doesn't really help
public object Convert(object obj) 
{
   if (obj == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    // Target method is always a private, instance method
    var bFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    // ..which takes a parameter of the obj's type.      
    var parameterTypes = new[] { obj.GetType() };

    // Get a MethodInfo instance that represents the correct overload
    var method = typeof(CrmToRealTypeConverter)
                 .GetMethod("Convert", bFlags, null, parameterTypes, null);

    if (method == null)
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert " + obj.GetType());

    // Invoke the method with the forwarded argument
    return method.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });
}
```

Comment: I always get null method with the reflection method. EDIT: Nevermind

Comment: It does, it was a bug in the programmer, not in the program

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism doesn't work on arguments to a method call. An approach you can use it to check the type of obj, cast it to the specific type and then call the appropriate overload.

```
public object Convert(object obj)
{
    if (obj is CrmDateTime)
        return Convert((CrmDateTime)obj);
    if (obj is CrmNumber)
        return Convert((CrmNumber)obj);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is that the best practice C# has to offer? Also the compiler says: Error 2 Cannot convert type 'T' to 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.CrmDateTime' C:\Documents and Settings\omerk\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Agile.CRMActiveRecord\Agile.CRMActiveRecord\CrmToRealTypeConverter.cs 14 28 Agile.CRMActiveRecord

Comment: @the_drow: Do your Crm* classes have a common base type (other than object)? I would say tthat the best practice is to add Convert as a virtual (possibly abstract) method in the base class that is overridden in each class. This is of course not possible if these classes are not created by you.

Comment: I did not create those classes, also they do not have a common base class due to bad design.

Comment: Use extensions methods then. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The model you should follow is the model in the .Net Convert class, there is no reason for you to make the constructor a generic, it brings nothing to the table.  Change the convert routines to static methods and the class itself to static:

```
static class CrmToRealTypeConverter : IConverter
{
    #region IConverter Members

    public static DateTime? Convert(CrmDateTime obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (DateTime?)obj.UserTime : null;
    }

    public static int? Convert(CrmNumber obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (int?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    public static decimal? Convert(CrmDecimal obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (decimal?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    public static double? Convert(CrmDouble obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (double?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    public static float? Convert(CrmFloat obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (float?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    public static decimal? Convert(CrmMoney obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (decimal?)obj.Value : null;
    }

    public static bool? Convert(CrmBoolean obj)
    {
        return obj.IsNull == false ? (bool?)obj.Value : null;
    }
}
```

Then when you call one of the convert methods the compiler will select the proper overload to call:

```
CrmDateTime crmDate;
CrmToRealTypeConverter.Convert(crmDate);  // Will call the static DateTime? Convert(CrmDateTime obj) overload    
// or 
CrmNumber crmNum;
CrmToRealTypeConverter.Convert(crmNum);  // Will call the static int? Convert(CrmNumber obj) overload
// and so on...
```

**Edit**:
If you do the following:

```
CrmFloat num;
// ...
Object obj = num;
CrmToRealTypeConverter.Convert(obj);
```

it will not work as the compiler doesn't know the type to match the overload.  You would have to cast it and it will work:

```
CrmToRealTypeConverter.Convert((CrmFloat)obj);
```

Comment: And what if I pass an object, will it fail?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the compiler doesn't know the generic type of `T` until runtime and binds the call to `T = System.Object` at compile-time, and the only function suitable to take a System.Object is that function itself. However, in .NET 4, you can use the `dynamic` keyword to cause the runtime to select the correct overload dynamically based on T at runtime, which is what you are looking to happen.

Simple example:

```
class Main {
    static void somefunction(System.String str)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("In String overload");
    }
    static void somefunction(System.Object obj)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("In Object overload");
    }
    static void somegenericfunction<T>(T object)
    {
        somefunction(object);
    }
    static void dynamicfunction<T>(dynamic T object)
    {
        somefunction(object);
    }
    static void main(System.String[] args)
    {
        somegenericfunction("A string"); // Calls Object overload, even though it's a String.
        dynamicfunction("A string"); // Calls String overload
    }
}
```

Note that I don't actually have my compiler on hand and this might not compile literally, but close enough.